# out-of-core messages config in giraph

Tags: configuration, message, giraph

I was working with pregel and i noticed that when the jobs finish, They don't deallocate memory. so i searched and knew that the latest version "Version: 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT" doesn't have this problem so i  downloaded the latest version of giraph from apache giraph. the number of produced message is a lot in my algorithm and because all of them are in memory, my ram becomes full. so i searched the problem and found the out-of-core message config. i want to set "giraph.useOutOfCoreMessages=true" but this config doesn't exixt in the latest version. What;s the problem?
Thanks.